# ReactJS: How to get a functional parent component to call a function in a child class component

Tags: reactjs, components

I have come across discussions of how to get a parent class component to call a child class component and a few instances of other mixes but have yet to find a working example of calling a function in a class child component from a functional parent component.  Code for instance:

```
function ParentForm(props) {
  const parentDoSomething = () => {
       // Want to call child component function childDoSomething() somewhere in here.
 }
...
return (
   ... various visual elements, buttons, etc. ...
<ChildComponent />
...
);

// ----------------------------------

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
...
childDoSomething = () => {
   ... does something ...
}
```

You'd think there'd be an easy straightforward way to do this but it is eluding me.  Can anyone give me good working examples of this solution?  Thanks in advance as always.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a normal pattern to have a parent component manually executing code that's inside a child component. You should default to using a more standard approach: pass down props to the child, and have the child check those props and act accordingly. This could include the child component calling a function inside itself when it receives a certain prop.

But if you absolutely need to do this, then you will need to get a ref to the child component. Since your child component is a class component, this works out of the box:

```
function ParentForm(props) {
  const ref = useRef();
  const parentDoSomething = () => {
    ref.current.childDoSomething();
  }

  return (
    ...
    <ChildComponent ref={ref} />
  )
}
```

If the child is a function component it is more difficult, because you will have to construct an object that you want the ref to refer to, and then tell react about that object via forwardRef and useImperativeHandle:

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const childDoSomething = () => {

  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    childDoSomething
  }));

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Problem is, I am getting a Javascript error: 
Uncaught TypeError: ref.current is not a function

Comment: ok, are you doing `ref.current()` or `ref.current.childDoSomething()`? If the latter, are you passing the ref to the child component?

Comment: ref.current.childDoSomething().  Yes, am passing the ref to the child component.

Comment: If you log out `ref.current`, what do you see?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Try comparing your code with what i did here for differences: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-2uz1kb?file=/index.js

Comment: It says 'undefined'.

Comment: That would happen if you weren't passing the ref to the child (which you've said you're doing so we can discount that possibility), or if you were calling parentDoSomething before the first render completes. When are you calling it?

Comment: Sorry but that site is blocked from my work environment. :(

Comment: K, the most likely issue is that you're calling parentDoSomething too early. The code i showed will work correctly if you're calling parentDoSomething from a `useEffect`, or a dom event like an `onClick` (the link you can't access just has the code i showed, plus calling parentDoSomething in an onClick). If you call the function during rendering, `ref.current` will be undefined on the first render (because the child doesn't exist yet)

Comment: The page/component is definitely fully rendered before the action that creates the state wherein the parent is calling the child component function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `ref` as a param to `ChildComponent` and access it like `this.ref` instead of accessing like a prop `this.props.ref`. There you can bind functions to it.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = { current: { childDoSomething: this.childDoSomething } };
  }

  childDoSomething = () => {
    alert("Hello from child component");
  };

  render() {
    return <div>Child component</div>;
  }
}

function ParentForm(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const parentDoSomething = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.childDoSomething();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={parentDoSomething}>Call child function</button>
      <ChildComponent ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit sweet-davinci-erpk0p]

Comment: Thanks Amila but my child component is a class component as I said in my OP.  I need a solution that lets the parent component (a functional component) invoke a function in the child component (a class component).

Comment: @Matt Campbell, I have updated the answer and code sandbox with the class component.

Comment: Thank you Amila.  Appreciate the effort.  In my Dev Tools Console I am getting an error: "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"  I get back 'undefined' for the ref.current, too.

Comment: Nope, no need to use `forwardRef`, the given example works well. can you confirm whether the structure you have with you is same as the updated answer?